# What are the protocols that can be embedded in Arduino?

Tags: arduino, protocols, messaging, iot

I am looking forward to implement messaging protocols in `Arduino` device. Most of the time the embedded systems will be client of some remote server and they will be communicating to this remote server using the these `IoT` protocols.

`MQTT` was trivial but other protocols aren't easily portable like I found no `Arduino` support for `CoAP`.

What are other protocols that can be embedded in `Arduino` (`Yun`)?

Comment: Are you looking for network protocol over TCP/IP or wired protocol like  I2C ?

Comment: I am looking for communication `IoT` protocols like CoAP, MQTT etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround specifically for `Yun` and considered myself answering this question. You can simply import library in the Linux (`Linino`) side of `Yun` by accessing the root.

```
ssh root@<yunaddress>
```

Use `Python` to create/import repository for the library you want for some specific protocol. To install some package like python, use:

```
opkg install <packagename>
```

If you want to work with C/C++ libraries, work with:

```
$ opkg install yun-gcc
$ opkg install make
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Paho provides [library](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/technology.paho/downloads) for Arduino, which is really good
Also on googling found out that there is a [CoAP implementation](https://github.com/dgiannakop/Arduino-CoAP)

Comment: CoAP implementation works with XbeeRadio that is deprecated technology. WIreless communication new standards doesn't support that. and Paho is for mqtt that i have already implemented